# What is an efficient way to set CSS class for each cell in a given table row?

Tags: javascript, css, no-framework

I have a problem setting the CSS class for each cell in a given table row. Initially I thought setting the parent row CSS would affect the style properties of cells, 
but that doesn't work. Instead I have to loop through all the cells in a given row to updated the CSS class.

However this is not efficient. And it took a lot of time. Consider my situation: I have around 230 rows in which each row has 23 cells (totally 5290 cells).

**Note:** I don't use any frameworks. so please can you suggest an approach in native JS?

**UPDATE :**

its working fine using the Paolo's recommendation..

Initially my custom css class is been like this

```
.Grid_RowItalicsBold { PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; COLOR: Black; LINE-HEIGHT: 15pt; FONT-STYLE: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow; TEXT-DECORATION: none }
```

And i changed this to

```
tr.Grid_RowItalicsBold td{ PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; OVERFLOW: hidden; COLOR: Black; LINE-HEIGHT: 15pt; FONT-STYLE: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow; TEXT-DECORATION: none }
```

And i assigned this class to my specific rows using javascript. :)

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish it might be easier to just give the row a class and then in your stylesheet reference the cells by using tr.rowclass td

Comment: @kris, the classes used in cells are common for entire cells.. i need to update only the selective rows.. so i cant just update that...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is then. What can't you do that my answer didn't cover?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why can't you set the class of the row and adjust your css accordingly?

```
<tr class="myclass">
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Then in CSS:

```
tr.myclass td {
    ...
}
```

In either case, assuming the table has an id of "mytable" you could give all the table rows the class you want like so:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
    rows[x].className = rows[x].className + " myclass";
}
```

If you're doing this to the whole table, though, you might as well just give a class to the table tag itself then do:

```
table.myclass tr td {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was just about to submit a very similar answer. Here's an upvote for you instead. :-)

Comment: @Paolo, i forgot to mention that..  the ids are auto generated.. i dont have the control over that.. (Its actually a intrnal Grid component)

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, your approach is working fine... I have updated my question... :)

Answer (score 2):

> @kris, the classes used in cells are common for entire cells.. i need to update only the selective rows.. so i cant just update that...

It still seems like you should be using CSS selectors to do what you want. Maybe something like this:

```
  #mytable td {
    // regular td style
  }
  #mytable .special td {
    // special cell style
  }
```

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="special">
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Initially I thought setting the parent
>   row CSS would affect the style
>   properties of cells, but that doesn't
>   work.

I think that if you set some of your cell's properties to "inherit" they will inherit those properties from the table row. Have you tried that?