# How can i loop through table in td using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following table structure and i want to loop through table inside my `td`. Please help me with same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to set CSS class for each cell in a given table row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593083/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-set-css-class-for-each-cell-in-a-given-table-row)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table').find('td').each(function(){
   //Do Something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.my-table tr td').each(function(index, td) {
    //block of code
    }
})
```